# Transforming data sampled by different machines

Tags: data-transformation

I am working with data that was taken by similar machines. These machines apparently were calibrated slightly differently, thus the data is a bit different. Using the same features, and the same algorithm, I get higher results by learning each data set separately, rather than trying to combine both sets. Is there a method which can learn how to transform one set to the other?

Sorry for the somewhat vagueness of this question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main question is: what are you doing with the data and what are you predicting?

If you need to predict something for all machines - then it would be a good idea to use all the data together. The accuracy may be lower, but it will be more stable in general.

If you can make predictions for each machine separately - do it.

As for transformation: compare the data, calculate the differences between the data from machines and make the relevant adjustments. Or scale the data in similar way.

Comment: I am training a classifier to predict something for all the machines. I did try scaling the different machines separately, but that failed miserably.
Anyhow, thanks for answering my vague question :)